# keep shopping cart items after logged in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i add items to the cart and login the items in the cart is deleted.so i want to move guest's shopping cart items to logged in user's basket.
i'm using angularjs and i'm thinking about using $window.localStorage()

scenario:

- Add itemes to the cart
- Login or signup
- cart will be empty

here is the my functions

```
        Auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function (currentUser) {
        if(currentUser) {
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + 
            currentUser.uid).once('value').then(function (loggedUser) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.user_type = loggedUser.val().user_type;
                });
            });
        }
    });

   $scope.$on('getAuth', function () {
        DashboardService.getOrders().then(function (orders) {
            model.length = orders.length;
            $scope.$apply()
        });
    });


    $scope.$on('OrdersUpdate', function (event, args) {
        model.length = DashboardService.allOrders.length;
    });


    function signOut() {
        DashboardService.allOrders = [];
       // $state.go('home-page');
        Auth.$signOut();
       $window.localStorage.clear();
        $location.path('/');
    }
```

Comment: Details about cart should be saved in database when user adds it. When the user logs in, it should be populated from database

Comment: Where’s the code that clears the cart after login or creating an account? Is the cart being cleared or the identifier changing? What will happen when the user adds items in an anonymous session then authenticates?

Comment: well, this is what I trying to figure out  i want the items added to the cart  in an anonymous session to show up  when a user login or sign up, also i noticed when a user signs out the items show up in the cart cuz I used $window.localstorage.clear()

Comment: @SandeshGupta the details are already saved in the database but when the user not log in it saves with a generated id and when user log in it has a diffrent id so it dose not  match each other, how can i make it match so i can compare between them?